# (Java) Thread won't execute

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I main C# and started to develop in Java. I am having trouble to start a Thread :(

```
public class GetLocationInfo implements Runnable{

String address;
double latitude;
double longitude;

public void run() {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=42.993504,-79.239167&sensor=false");
    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;


    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("formatted_address")) {
                address = reader.nextString();
            } else
                reader.skipValue();
        }
        reader.endObject();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}


public String GetAddress(double lat, double lng) {

    latitude = lat;
    longitude = lng;

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);

    thread.start();
    return address;
}
}
```

I've set break points in the overridden run() method, and nothing seems to execute within this method. If you guys can help me straighten this out it would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: you left the catch blocks blank. Add `e.printStackTrace();` for each catch block and check if an exception is thrown

Comment: you just started the thread. How do you expect `address` to be filled already?

Answer (score 1):

Do not advise using this way of taking the location, I would use google services play a good example here.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm

if you are determined to use that code I recommend you use AsyncTask
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a few important points about threads by assuming the main thread is somehow going to stop and wait for the newly created thread to execute its `run()` method before returning.
When working with threads, keep the following in mind:

1. When you start the thread in your `GetAddress()` method it doesn't mean it will call it's run method immediately and just proceed to returning the computed address when it gets back as if you have called the run method without creating a new thread. You wouldn't even need another thread if you wanted just that. When you start a second thread you are basically telling the OS that there is a new thread ready to run but is up to the OS to decide exactly when the code in that thread will actually start. Even in a multiple CPU/core environment you can't assume that a core will be available at that exact point.
2. You can't also assume that the main thread will stop or pause it's execution just because it started another thread. The main thread may eventually stop executing for a brief moment to allow other threads to execute but only when there are not enough cores in the system to run all the threads in parallel. Anyway you can't predict when or if it is going to happen. This means that after starting the new thread, it is a lot more likely that the method `GetAddress()` will proceed returning the current value of the address variable to its caller before the newly created thread finished or even started its `run()` method.
   If you are unsure about that being true, try inserting the following lines after starting the thread:

   ```
   thread.start();
   try {                // Used just for demonstration purposes
       thread.join();   // This block kills the parallelism of the second thread
   }
   return address;
   ```

This code forces the main thread to wait for the newly created thread to execute. **Note however, that this code will spoil any benefits of creating a new thread.**

So what now?

You have many ways to deal with multiple threads and I can't tell you what is the best method without knowing a lot more about your project; but I can give you a few directions through a very simple example.
Let's say you have a program with an UI, a button to get the address and a text field where the address will be written to. When someone clicks the button, instead of trying to compute the address in one shot, you call a method like `startRetrievingAddress()` in which you would start the worker thread and fill the text field with a temporary text like `"please wait..."`. At the end of the working thread's `run()` method you could add code to fill the text field with the final result.
An even better way to do it would be to create a working thread class with support for "completition" listeners that would be notified when the run method is done computing the address so they have a chance of dealing with the results as soon as they are computed. Then you would register a listener in which you'd be setting the text field with the computed value.
Sure there are even better ways of doing this using looper thread to deal with messages issued from worker threads and all but I can't mention them all here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you Encapsulate the 'core activity' in a class that implements runnable or callable (If you wish to get a Future result). Use [ThreadpoolExecutors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to submit tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for giving some answers. Although, the way it is coded may not be the best practice, I found a solution.

Just created a constructor for the class and started the thread there and made the string variable address public.

```
public class GetLocationInfo implements Runnable{

public String address;
double latitude;
double longitude;

public GetLocationInfo(double lat, double lng) {

    latitude = lat;
    longitude = lng;

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);

    thread.start();

}

public void run() {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=42.993504,-79.239167&sensor=false");
    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;


    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String name = reader.nextName();
            if (name.equals("formatted_address")) {
                address = reader.nextString();
            } else
                reader.skipValue();
        }
        reader.endObject();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are a number of reasons this won't work the way you want it to. First, how does the other thread, which uses address, know when it has been populated? Are you just going to loop (wastes cpu)? The 'FutureTask' class was made for this scenario - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html . Calling 'get' on it waits until the thread completes. If you're not going to do this, you at least need to make your address field 'volatile'. Otherwise, java provides no guarantee that your other thread will be able to see the value.